# List view item touch feedback not applied to whole row

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-listview

Whenever I tap one of my list view items, only the text area within the item gets highlighted and not the rest of the row. How can I fix this error to enable touch feedback the whole row of any list view item?

**Java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    ListView list_main;

    String[] listContent = {
            "Item 1",
            "Item 2",
            "Item 3",
            "Item 4",
            "Item 5"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list_main = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_main);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listContent);
        list_main.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

**XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_main"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: change ListView layout_width to "match_parent"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your ListView width to match parent. That way the list item will be a full row.